# Results from table() into row of a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, contingency

I've been looking for solutions to this problem without much luck. 
I'm looping over files, to get contingency tables of proportions. Example:

```
df<-data.frame("Ind"=c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"), "Highest"=c("W","W","BCW","BCW","W"))
tabledf<-table(df$Highest)/length(df$Highest)
```

I would like to fill in an 'empty' data frame with the results of the table above:

```
results<-data.frame("F"=0, "W"=0,"F1"=0,"F2"=0,"BCF"=0,"BCW"=0)
results[1,]<-???
```

obviously the question marks are where I go wrong. I have a code written to loop over all the files, create the contingency tables for each one, but I'm not sure how to tell it to fill in results[i,] with each table, especially as, as in the example above, not all categories are present in every table. I've tried match() without errors, but it only returns NAs.

I would like the final product to look something like:

```
>results

   F  W   F1  F2  BCF  BCW
1  0  0.6 0   0   0    0.4
```

with additional rows for the other files I'm looping over.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the names of `tabledf` to subset `results`:

```
results[names(tabledf)] <- tabledf
results
#  F   W F1 F2 BCF BCW
#1 0 0.6  0  0   0 0.4
```

Or if this is part of a for-loop you can still do: `results[1, names(tabledf)] <- tabledf`

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your vector a `factor` and specify the possible `levels`:

```
table(factor(df$Highest,lev=c("F","W","F1","F2","BCF","BCW")))/length(df$Highest) 

  F   W  F1  F2 BCF BCW 
0.0 0.6 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.4
```

**EDIT**
To get the data in a `data.frame`, you could do:

```
result <-data.frame(t(as.vector(tabledf)))
colnames(result) <- names(tabledf)
result

  F   W F1 F2 BCF BCW
1 0 0.6  0  0   0 0.4
```

Comment: @EmmaSylvester I edited my answer to add the result to a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

library(`dplyr`) could be helpful here.

```
df %>% group_by(Highest) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>% mutate(freq=N/sum(N))
```

You would then need to loop over this for every file. Hope this gets you on the right track.